# How to find the limit of a dynamical system?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

> Consider the dynamical system $$
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1.25 & -0.75 \\
>         -0.75 & 1.25 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   Suppose
>   $$x_0 =
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1  \\
>         -1  \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   Compute $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x_k$

Comment: Have you attempted to compute the limit? Can you give any more information regarding the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you mean by "limit". For sure, the entries matrix itself do not approach a limit. This can be seen by calculating the eigenvalues of the matrix. The Characteristic Equation comes out to be $(1.25-\lambda)^2=9/16$ from which one eigenvalue happens to be $2$ which is more than $1$. So subjecting your vector to high powers of the matrix results in a vector that "spins" out of control, rather than approaching to "fixed" position in the xy plane